# jsAccountLimits::MaxBytesRequired is a bool ean, should it be int64_t?

Tags: nats.io

The NATS C Client structure `jsAccountInfo` has a member `Limits` that holds a `jsAccountLimits` structure.

This structure in turn has a member `MaxBytesRequired` of which the datatype is a `bool`.

Shouldn't that member be define `int64_t` as are the other `jsAccountInfo::Limits::...` members?

I tried to give the boolean meaning, but i don't find any, hence it wonder if this is a declaration error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question on the GitHub board of NATS C Client and the following answer was provided by the developing team:

> No, this is really a boolean. It is an account's limit that forces all
> streams to require a MaxBytes value to be set. In other word, if this
> boolean is enabled for the account limit and a stream is created
> without MaxBytes value, the stream creation will fail.

Hence the name MaxBytesRequired must be read as: **Do all streams need to be forced to have a MaxBytes value set.**

This is on an Account basis.